# noUiSlider handle has two little vertical lines that don't disappear after styling

Tags: handle, nouislider

I have changed the style of handles of noUiSlider. I got the shape I wanted, narrow vertical lines. But I found the default shape of handles has double short lines and they don't disappear after I change the styling. You may see the double short lines under the handles. Could anyone help remove the double short lines in the default handles?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out myself. Add below in CSS then the double lines in noUiSlider handles disappear.

```
.noUi-handle:before, .noUi-handle:after {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: minor issue: there is "." missing in front of the 2nd selector.